# Make elements below accordion shift down when a heading is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I have an accordion. Under the accordion are other elements of the page. I want that when any of the accordion headers are clicked and contents shown, the elements below accordion shift down. Somebody help!

```
$("h3").click( function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    if ($(this).hasClass("isDown") ) {  
        $(".basic-grey").css('margin-top','213%');  
        $("#skills").animate({top:"-=65%"});            
        $(".updown").animate({top:"-=65%"});
        $("#contact").animate({top:"-=65%"});                               
        $(this).removeClass("isDown");
    } 
    else {  
        $(".basic-grey").css('margin-top','180%');  
        $("#skills").animate({top:"+=65%"});
        $(".updown").animate({top:"+=65%"});                        
        $("#contact").animate({top:"+=65%"});                           
        $(this).addClass("isDown");
    }
    return false;
})
```

I've already tried this method after reading from another example and it doesn't work if I don't click on the same accordion heading that I opened to close the content again. For eg. if I clicked on "Academics" to show content in "Academics" and then I click on "Work",(which opens work and automatically closes the content under "Academics") the content gets shifted down twice and looks weird.

Comment: We can achieve this in much simpler way. We can hide / show the element. As, a result the contents will shift automatically. Since, in `hide` remove DOM element.

Comment: I'm using the jquery built-in accordion. How do I change the setting of the accordion to use hide/show when I click the h3 headings? Wouldn't I be losing the sliding style of showing content that the accordion has by doing this?

Comment: oh ok.. Can you make jsFiddle with plugin and share here. Thanks.

Comment: @jeek online http://jsfiddle.net/nakulpathak3/MfegM/1680/
Looks a bit different from what it's like on my browser but basically, it's that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing, i saw the fiddle and it is quit complex as you are using knockout.js and jquery-ui. I am not much aware of that. I will try to update on this soon.

Comment: Hi there is no knockout.js used. It is only jquery.